# How do I display text from a MYSQL database using javascript

Tags: javascript, mysql, javascript-objects

How do I get data from MYSQL key/value pairs into a javascript object. I use php, javascript and HTML5.

Comment: "This is a continuation from my previous question". Could you please post the link of your "previous" question here?

Comment: - or better yet make it so this question sands on its own

Comment: Please edit your question with the details of the previous question as it makes no sense in its current form.

Comment: Sorry to confuse you, the question was the last line which I have modified the rest was to give you some background into the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are not using another programing languages beside JS and MYSQL, and you need an internal language to communicate them.

Javascript is a client language and SQL is a server language, so you need another programming language to connect them (like PHP, RoR, Java, etc...) for security reason, can you imagine what could happen if in your computer is the login and password of the DB of any bank?

If you want to learn some other PHP you can take a look here: http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLD1E8E67698E6A612 or http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.php

Or RoR, you can go to railscast.com.

Comment: I have edited my question. The majority was to give a background into my problem. The question was the last line which I have modified.

Answer (score 0):

create a div containing database excerpt, onClick, div expands. QED.